# Why does this Standard ML bubblesort's loop only execute once?

Tags: while-loop, reference, sml, bubble-sort, ml

So I tried to implement [bubblesort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Pseudocode_implementation) using ML's reference types. I compiled the code in Poly/ML and it seems that the "while(!flag)" loop only executes once for any input.

For example: [2,3,1] gets "sorted" to [2,1,3], i.e. the first loop worked but the second never ran.

"Flag up" got printed once.

What's wrong?

Thanks.

```
fun bubbleSort l =        (* l being a list of references *)
let
    val it = ref 0        (* iterator variable *)
    val len = length l
    val flag = ref true   (* to be set to true when a swap is made *)
in
    while (!flag) do
    (
        flag := false;
        while ((!it) < (len-1)) do
        (
            if (get l (!it)) > (get l ((!it)+1))
            then (swap_next l (!it); flag := true; TextIO.print "Flag up\n")
            else ();
            it := (!it) + 1
        )
    )
end;
```

Full code of the module I wrote, if needed, can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/Meyv6yVy).

Comment: Drive-by comment: 53.33% (measured precisely) of your parentheses are redundant.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware some of them were gonna be redundant but I'm preparing hastily for an exam where correctness is much more important than style so I let it slide :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bubblesort repeatedly scans over the same array. Your inner loop scans over it just once but never resets the counter `it`. Before the line

```
while ((!it) < (len-1)) do
```

You should put the line

```
it := 0;
```

Comment: Or move the `let val it = ref 0` into the outer loop.